# passing env variables to commands in bash

Tags: bash

I have this sample bash command:

```
FILE='/tmp/1.txt' echo "file: $FILE"
```

and the output is:

```
file:
```

Why the output doesn't contain defined earlier variable FILE?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you run

```
FILE='/tmp/1.txt' echo "file: $FILE"
```

The shell expands the $FILE variable before performing the assignment, so assuming FILE was unset previously, you'd get:

```
FILE='/tmp/1.txt' echo "file: "
```

You can confirm this behavior by setting FILE to a known value first:

```
FILE="foo"
FILE='/tmp/1.txt' echo "file: $FILE"
```

The second line is expanded to:

```
FILE='/tmp/1.txt' echo "file: foo"
```

Then the value of FILE, in the context of this command, is changed to `/tmp/1.txt`.  Then the shell executes `echo "file: foo"`

As @admstg mentioned in his response, you can do:

```
FILE='/tmp/1.txt'; echo "file: $FILE"
```

But that behavior is different than what you were originally trying.  What you had initially sets FILE only for the duration of the echo command; the above sets it for the duration of the shell (or until it is explicitly unset).

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the two commands by ; in order to define the variable then by calling it.

As you are calling the variable in the same shell you don't need to export the variable.

This should work :

```
FILE='/tmp/TEST.txt' ;  echo "file : $FILE"
```